# ffmpeg command throwing "Invalid duration specification for ss: 00:00:00,000"

Tags: python, ffmpeg

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:00,000 -to 00:00:03,466 -c:v copy output.mp4

The above is my ffmpeg command which is throwing the error of "Invalid duration specification for ss 00:00:00,000". I think it is throwing the error because of the timestamp format. It is not taking input of milliseconds. That is why it is not executing the full command. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Try 00:00:00:000 format

Comment: @TanishqBanyal thanks for the suggestion, but the timestamp is being fetched from the .json file and ffmpeg command should work with that format of timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#time-duration-syntax) clearly specifies the format of timestamp to be

> [-][HH:]MM:SS[.m...]

So you'll need to somehow convert your input by replacing the comma with a "." in the timestamp to make it work.

Also, [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/141343/839615) also suggests the same.

Comment: can we change hh:mm:ss,ms into hh:mm:ss.ms programmatically in python? Like replacing "," with "."?

Comment: Yes, you can use .replace() method in python. For example use string.replace(",", ".") to replace "," in your string variable with "."

Comment: thanks for the advice. That really worked.